# http connection over WiFi on android

Tags: android

I am using org.apache.http.*; API's to make HTTP Post Connections over Internet from the Android Application. I added the Internet Permissions in the Manifest file and it works fine. Now i want my application to make the same HTTP requests over WiFi network through which the handset is connected.

Do i need to make code changes to achieve this? Do i need to add some permissions?
as i am unable to make requests...

Can someone help me on this...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Concerning simple HTTP-requests, Android doesn't care about the type of you internet-connection (as long as its there) so no code- and/or permission-changes are necessary.

I have build HTTP-requests with Android myself and never ran into those problems - maybe some of your code as well as any error you're getting (what does "unable to make requests" mean??) will help to clarify.